# Algorithm for sorting an 2D array

Tags: sorting

Given a 2 dimensional array (a matrix) with n rows and n columns, with it's rows and columns sorted, what would be the efficient algorithm to sort it?

For example:

Input

```
1 5  8     
3 6  9      
8 12 15
```

Output:

```
1 3 5 6 8 8 9 12 14 15
```

I want a pseudo code that solve problem in best time.

Comment: Do you want to sort it into a single dimension array?

Comment: What language are you looking for?

Comment: @Krimson I want a pseudo code.

Comment: In what sense are the columns of your example sorted?

Comment: then I recommend mpcabd's answer.

Comment: my previous example was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The first idea that comes to my mind is to generalize the "Merge Two Sorted Arrays" algorithm.

- Maintain n pointers, each pointer for a row in your 2D array.
- Each iteration compare all the pointers and pick the minimum value.
- Push the minimum value to the result array.
- Advance the pointer for that minimum value row.
- Make sure you don't compare pointers beyond the row length.

This will be an `O(n^2)` algorithm.

Also take a look at this solution here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-k-sorted-arrays/

**Update: 06:30 UTC**

Also one other idea that came to my mind is to merge each two rows separately, and recursively repeat the process, this will be an `O(n.log(n))` algorithm.

Comment: i guess the best time is O(n^2) but this algorithm take more time.

Comment: No the worst case of this algorithm would be `O(n^2)`. I've also updated my answer to suggest another solution.

Comment: why the worst case has O(n^2)?
for exmaple input [1 2 3 4] [5 6 7 8] [9 10 11 12] [13 14 15 16]. It takes more than O(n^2). because finding minimum takes O(n) and we do this $n^2$ times. it take O(n^3).

Comment: For me I was counting n as the full size of the matrix, so in worst case you'd be comparing each item to all the items in the array and it'd be `O(n^2)`. So basically your comment and mine are the same :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it shouldn't take more than O(n log(n)) under any circumstance since this is what we get for quick sort without considering the sorted rows and columns.

probably you would get a good answer using merge function in merge sort. call it recursively. but again it would give you O(n log(n)). although when it reaches size of sqrt(n) it will return instead of going all the way to problem with size 1. but still log( n sqrt(n) ) has the same order of growth as n log(n) but in real problem this would probably give you a better result.

EDIT:
I assumed we merge rows or columns (doesn't make any difference).

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your question as to what language you are looking in to?

**In python:**

```
>>> x = [[1, 5, 8, 10],
[3, 4, 5, 6],
[2, 3, 3, 9]]
>>> x = sorted([items for sub in x for items in sub])
>>> print x
[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10]
```

*Pseudo-code*

Create an empty list

Loop over the matrix,

get the smallest value,

append it to the empty list,

and remove that value from the matrix.

Comment: He wants to sort a 2d array. What you have is a 1D array. In python a 2D array would be a list of list: `[[...], [...], [...], ...]`

Comment: input has sorted row in my problem.

Comment: What do you mean by *sorted row*?

Answer (score 0):

Change fast sort algorithm to access your 2d array as 1d. Like this:

before:

```
sort(array){
    ...
    for(i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
        if(array[i]){
    ...
}
```

after:

```
sort(array){
    ...
    for(i = 0; i < M * N; i++){
        if(array[i/N][i%N]){
    ...
}
```